# Pandasで予め商品ごとのメーカーリストを使用し、仕入れリストの商品詳細からメーカーを特定・自動入力したい。

Tags: python, pandas

Pandasにて以下の処理を行いたいです。

DataFrame1

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

- DataFrame1 は仕入れリストです。
- A, B, C, D は商品名とします。
- %は関係ない文字・数字とします

DataFrame 2

[image: リスト項目]

<実行したいこと＞
①DataFrame1に、"Marker"という列を追加します。
②DataFrame1の"Product_Description"の行から、Dataframe2の"Product_Name"に記載した商品名を関係のない文字・数値が入ってる中から特定　
③DataFrame1の"Marker"の行に、各商品ごとのメーカー名が自動的に入力。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記の処理を行うには、まず１）DataFrame2 から、Product_NameをキーとしたMarkerの辞書を作る、2) DataFrame1の"Product_Description"を１行ずつ読み込む, 3) 読み込んだ文字列の中にMaker辞書のキーのどれかが含まれていないかサーチする, 4) 含まれていれば対応するMakerの値をDataFrame1のMakerに入れる

で、実行できると考えておりますが、Pythonを最近勉強し始めてたばかりのため、コードを上手く書けません。。。
今後の参考として、どのたかご回答を頂けますと大変助かります＞＜
宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/266130

Answer (score 1):

この記事の回答でコメントを受けて訂正した部分が、まさに実行したい手順を実現しているようです。
[Pandas: using str.contains and map to find some substring and replace value in column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40177398/9014308)

> EDIT by comment:
> It seems there is no match by dict, you can test it by sample:
>
> ```
> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'device_id':['a d','b s','c r'], 'b':[1,2,3]})    
> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['a','m','k'], 'category':['one','two','three']})    
> #df2 = pd.DataFrame({'url':['a r','m','k'], 'category':['one','two','three']})    
>
> d = df2.set_index('url')['category'].to_dict()
> print (d)
> {'k': 'three', 'a': 'one', 'm': 'two'}
>
> df1['category']=df1.device_id.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in d.items() if k in x])) 
> print (df1)
>    b device_id category
> 0  1       a d      one
> 1  2       b s      NaN
> 2  3       c r      NaN
> ```

質問の内容に当てはめると、以下のようになるでしょう。
ちなみに`Marker`は`Maker`のtypoでしょう。
あと3つ目の画像で玉ねぎとコーヒーの順番が変わっているのには対応していません。

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
  'Product_Description': 
    [ '%%%人参%%%%',
      '%%%%%%ポテト%%',
      '%%%%玉ねぎ%%%%%',
      '%%%コーヒー%%%%%']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
  "Product_Name": 
    [ '人参',
      'ポテト',
      '玉ねぎ',
      'コーヒー'],
  "Maker": 
    [ 'A社',
      'B社',
      'B社',
      'C社']
})

df2dict = df2.set_index('Product_Name')['Maker'].to_dict()
print(df2dict)

df1['Maker'] = df1.Product_Description.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([v for k,v in df2dict.items() if k in x]))

print(df1)
```

表示結果
df2dict

```
{'人参': 'A社', 'ポテト': 'B社', '玉ねぎ': 'B社', 'コーヒー': 'C社'}
```

df1

```
  Product_Description Maker
0           %%%人参%%%%    A社
1         %%%%%%ポテト%%    B社
2        %%%%玉ねぎ%%%%%    B社
3        %%%コーヒー%%%%%    C社
```